# Does including enum columns in cassandra primary affects cassandra load balancing or not?

Tags: java, enums, cassandra, primary-key

Consider a table creation:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;
CREATE TABLE my_table
  (my_id varchar,
  my_date varchar,
  enum_one varchar,
  enum_two varchar
  PRIMARY KEY (my_id, my_date, enum_one, enum_two)
);
```

Columns `enum_one` and `enum_two` has fixed numbers of value (6 and ~20). Should I include enum columns to primary key or not?

Consider a situation when I have many rows with one `enum_one` value and a few with other values.
How does cassandra handle this situation - does it balance loading or most requests go to one node?

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra load balances based on the partition key, so if you included the enum columns in the partition key, then it would have an effect on the load balancing.

In your example, you are using my_id as the partition key.  If your reads and writes tend to have different values for my_id, then this should keep your data balanced.

If your reads and writes tend to mostly use just a few values for my_id (i.e. if my_id has low cardinality), then the data will not be well load balanced across the Cassandra nodes.  If that is the case, then including the enum fields would increase the cardinality of the partition key and result in a more evenly balanced data load.

The flip side of this is that using a different partition key may impact what types of queries you can do efficiently.  It is efficient to query for data within a single partition, so if you included the enum columns in the partition key, then you would have to query for each value of the enum columns in separate queries instead of a single query.